# footer won't stretch the full width of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a footer in twitter bootstrap, but for some reasons it doesn't stretch the full with.

```
<div id="footer">

</div>

#footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #b85e45;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

As you can see it's pretty simple.

Comment: Can you please create plunker/jsfiddle for the same? In the meantime you just check with one thing that the wrapper class is container-fluid and NOT container?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hansselten/xxn5xoqk/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. However, I am on vacation for a couple of days. Debugging on phone is not possible. Please allow me 24 hours - Once back will work on your issue as the first thing. Apologies for delay

Comment: Added my answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Take your time Nikhil I'm not in a hurry but it's so frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another style

```
html, body {

margin : 0;
padding : 0;

}
```

It will work.

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xxn5xoqk/1/

Comment: I was hoping it would :) but it didn't. Sometimes bootstrap can be so frustrating.

Comment: In the fiddle you shared - there was no bootstrap. Only simple html with 1 div and css with 1 style and in that adding above style worked. I have added the updated fiddle. So, this works in sample application, however, if in your actual application, even after this there is a problem. See whether the footer is inside an element with class container. If yes, change it to container fluid.

Comment: Hi, no it still doesn't work. And it's not in a container.

Comment: Hi, did you checked the fiddle? It is working in the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin on "body" to "0":

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4fdgnjpq/) is a working example